# How to search a json encoded array column in a table with respect to an array and return the matching result?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a mysql table that contains a column `user_ids` - this column holds json encoded array of user ids.
Just like this -

```
row0 - "[145,146]", 
row1 - "[145]", 
row2 - "[141,143,145]", 
row3 - "[142,146,147]"
```

Now I want to search inside the `user_ids` column for each row with respect to another array of `user_ids` supplied as an argument. I want all the matched rows to be returned as a result of this query.

I have tried to implement it like this in Laravel but it didn't return any rows-

```
$booked_courses = $booked_courses->where(function ($query) use ($user_ids) {
    $query->orWhere('user_ids', 'LIKE', '%'.json_encode($user_ids).'%');
});
```

Also I thought looping over the decoded array might yield the result but didn't succeed, tried to do the following -

```
$booked_courses = $booked_courses->where(function ($query) use ($user_ids) {
    foreach(json_decode($query->user_ids) as $u_id) {
        $query->whereIn($u_id, $user_ids);
    }
});
```

Any help in raw sql as well, will be very helpful for me. Or please suggests me some ways to fetch the desired result. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Try `JSON_SEARCH` in mysql and you can use `raw where` in laravel

Comment: Can you show what `$user_ids` looks like?